# LINQ to SQL: "Method 'Boolean Contains(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a hashset of strings representing tmdbId's for movies I have on disk - called moviesOnDisk.

I have a database of movie objects, indexed on the `tmdbId`.

I want to delete the records that exist in the database but don't exist on disk.

I have this line to get the difference:

```
var toDelete = Database.Movies.Where(x => !moviesOnDisk.Contains(x.TMDbId));
```

this gives me no results and the following message:

> Method 'Boolean Contains(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Is there a work around for this? Obviously I can iterate over both lists, but I am going for best performance.

Comment: var toDelete = Database.Movies.Where(x => !moviesOnDisk).Contains(x.TMDbId);

Comment: Your statement should work. `moviesOnDisk` is definitely a `HashSet<String>`, right?

Comment: yep it is - I'm really confused why it's throwing an exception...

Comment: @user3689167 Change it to this: `((IEnumerable<String>)moviesOnDisk).Contains(x.TMDbId)`. Alternatively, you can use a `List<String>` if you're only building `moviesOnDisk` for this query.

Comment: Try changing it to `moviesOnDisk.Any(x => x.Id = TMDbId)` or `moviesOnDisk.ToList().Contains(x.TMDbId)`

Comment: that works Rob, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @user3689167 what works? :) I think all 3 approaches mentioned in comments "should" work...

Comment: @user3689167 It works because `Contains` is a specific implementation on `HashSet<String>`. When translating to SQL, it has a set of supported methods, including `Queryable.Contains()` - which is a different method from what you've written. `HashSet<String>.Contains` has a different implementation (that is, hashing the value and doing a lookup), and can't be converted to SQL.

Comment: Mutu's did not. Rob's did. Your first suggestion implies that moviesOnDisk was a HashSet<Movie> instead of a HashSet<string>, but I'm sure your second suggestion would work. I was trying to use a hashset to leverage the quick computation of "is it there?". still very confused why it has to be casted to an ienumerable to call Contains on the hashset...edit: thanks Rob that makes sense now

Answer (score 5):

Change your where clause to `!moviesOnDisk.ToList().Contains(x.TMDbId)`.

@Rob provided a great explanation in comments on why `Contains` will work on `IEnumerable`, but not on a `HashSet`:

> It works because Contains is a specific implementation on
>   HashSet. When translating to SQL, it has a set of supported
>   methods, including Queryable.Contains() - which is a different method
>   from what you've written. HashSet.Contains has a different
>   implementation (that is, hashing the value and doing a lookup), and
>   can't be converted to SQL

Comment: If performance is an issue, I would recommend `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToList()` - the reason being is that `.ToList()` will enumerate the `HashSet`, build the list, and then the SQL generator will enumerate the list again - while casting to `IEnumerable` or using `.AsEnumerable()` will skip the first enumeration, and defer it to the SQL generator :)

Comment: Agreed. I am too used to use `ToList` on everything :) Fixed.

Comment: @Rob, do you mind posting your comment as an answer by the way? It is your solution really. I just wanted to have a proper answer to the questions to follow Q&A practices.

Answer (score -1):

change moviesOnDisk to array,it will work.
the type of array item must same as TMDbId